# Remove spaces and change 'et al.' to ’等‘ in citeauthor in natbib

Tags: citing, natbib, chinese

I am trying to use \citeautor to cite author names automatically in Chinese text as follows:

```
\citeauthor{key}提出了一种方法 \cite{key}。
```

which will result in:

```
A et al. 提出了一种方法[1]。
```

What I want is:

```
A等提出了一种方法[1]。
```

by:

1. remove the space before `et al.`
2. change `et al.` to `等`

Update:
I just tried to provide an MWE,but could not solve it. I am using this template from GitHub: https://github.com/1FCENdoge/SYSUThesis

Comment: Without any code that others can copy and test as is, it is vry hard to know what exactly you are doing and thus provide any help. Note that in general for `bibtex` keywords like `et al.` is baked into the `bibtex` style and is not really configurable in most cases. Have you considered using `biblatex` instead?

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information to answer your question. What `\bibliographystyle` are you using? But independent of that, `natbib` + `bibtex` isn't really set up to deal with Unicode `.bib` files, so you really should consider switching to `biblatex` + `biber`.

Comment: @daleif  Sorry for that. I just tried to add some example, but could not resolve it. I am using a template in https://github.com/1FCENdoge/SYSUThesis .The template is based on a .bst file. So I think only bibtex is available.

Comment: @AlanMunn The style is gbt7714-bibtex-style from https://github.com/zepinglee/gbt7714-bibtex-style. The template I am using is based on the .bst file. I'll see if I am able to change the template to use biblatex if it's the only option.

Comment: I'm very skeptical that this will work very well, but you can try adding `\renewcommand{\bibetal}{等}` and `\renewcommand{\biband}{和}` to your preamble. This class makes the mistake of trying to do too much for you, unfortunately, and it has quite a bit of `natbib` specific code, so it might be non-trivial to modify it to allow `biblatex`, although I'm sure that would be a better solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for your help. I tried the command, but errors occurred. I changed the class file to use latex, and it did work. But there is still space between the name and 'et al'. I'll give it up temporarily.